# Formatting moment from military time to am/pm

Tags: momentjs

I'm having a bit of difficulty with some of my moment formatting. From the database I'm getting back a string of 1-24 (military time) and I'm trying to use moment to format this (1am-12am) changing it from military time to a more legible one.

I have been playing with this for a while now, but all I can seem to get back from moment is the current time and can't figure out how to pass in the string.

I've tried

```
moment().format("hA");
```

and also

```
moment('15').format("hA");
```

and

```
moment(15).format("hA");
```

and a few other variations. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
moment("16", "hh").format('hA')
```